# ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar una función de un componente desde otro componente en angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

Investigue pero no he dado con nada en concreto, entonces me gustaría que por favor me ayudaran con esto, necesito una forma de ejecutar una función que se encuentra en un componenteB desde un componenteA, me gustaría que fuera mediante un servicio porque necesito trabajar con varios componentes a la vez, pero si no se puede hacer con los servicios me gustaría saber que alternativas tengo, intente algo como esto.

**componenteB**:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if( this.servicio.comprobacion == true ){
        this.funcionDos();
    }
}

funcionDos(): void {
    console.log("la funcionB fue ejecutada")
}
```

**servicio**:

```
comprobacion = false;
```

**componenteA**:

```
click(): void {
    servicio.comprobacion = true;
}
```

Bueno la idea es que cuando detecte el cambio ejecutara la función, aunque siendo la salida mas fácil no funcionara, mi pregunta es en este caso ¿que herramientas de angular me ayudarían a llegar hacer algo por el estilo?.

Como por ejemplo:

- @Input y @Output
- EventEmitter
- servicios
- Observables
- set y get

No se si ahora ignoro otra herramienta que tal vez también funcione para hacer esto, les agradecería mucho su ayuda, si necesitan mas información, porfa me lo hacen saber.

Comment: Según la [documentación oficial de Angular](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-using-a-service), puedes lograr que los componentes se comuniquen a través de un servicio. En [este link](https://fullstackdeveloper.guru/2020/03/31/how-to-communicate-between-angular-components-through-a-shared-service/) hay un ejemplo. Aquí [hay otro](https://www.thirdrocktechkno.com/blog/how-angular-components-communicate/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno aunque parezca algo complicado en realidad no lo es ;)

Imagina que tienes el componente A que quiere comunicarse con el componente B para saber si se presionó algún botón u ocurrió algún evento.

Para esto como bien mencionas podemos utilizar un servicio:

---

Para este ejemplo el servicio lo llamaremos **`mi-servicio-ejecutor.service.ts`**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class MiServicioEjecutorService {
  // Creamos un BehaviorSubject de tipo boolean
  public miVariable$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  constructor() { }
}
```

En este archivo como vez creamos un *[BehabiorSubject](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject)*, no creamos un observable porque a diferencia de éste en el BehabiorSubject podemos modificar el valor ;)

> Cuando instanciamos el *BehaviorSubject* agregamos entre parentesis el valor inicial que tendrá en este caso **false**

---

Una vez creado nuestro servicio vamos a crear un componente llamado "**comp-a**" y en el archivo *ts* (**`comp-a.component.ts`**) agregamos lo siguiente (Dejaré comentadas las líneas importantes):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MiServicioEjecutorService } from '../mi-servicio-ejecutor.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-comp-a',
  templateUrl: './comp-a.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comp-a.component.css']
})
export class CompAComponent implements OnInit {
  // En el constructor le decimos que utilizaremos el servicio creado anteriormente
  constructor(private miServicioEjecutor: MiServicioEjecutorService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Con el subscribe escuchamos si la variable sufrió algún cambio
    this.miServicioEjecutor.miVariable$.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(`El valor de la variable cambio a: ${data}`);
    });
  }
}
```

---

Finalmente agregamos el componente b (**comp-b**) que será quien ejecute o cambie en este caso el valor que tiene el servicio:

**`comp-b.component.ts`**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MiServicioEjecutorService } from '../mi-servicio-ejecutor.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-comp-b',
  templateUrl: './comp-b.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comp-b.component.css']
})
export class CompBComponent implements OnInit {
  // En el constructor le decimos que utilizaremos el servicio creado anteriormente
  constructor(private miServicioEjecutor: MiServicioEjecutorService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Cambiarmos el valor de la variable para que todos los componentes que estan subscritos detecten el cambio
    this.miServicioEjecutor.miVariable$.next(true);
  }
}
```

Ojo que en este caso la línea `this.miServicioEjecutor.miVariable$.next(true);` la puedes poner en un evento click o el que tú necesites ;)

Cuando utilizamos **`.next(true)`** es cuando asignamos el valor y cuando esto pasa entonces el **`.subscribe(...`** que utilizamos en el componente A que es el que esta escuchando todo el tiempo se entera del cambio y realiza la acción que le dijimos (en este caso mostrar el mensajito por consola).

> También hay otras formas de realizarlo pero mucho depende de la funcionalidad que quieras dar: si el componente esta dentro de otro, etc. Pero utilizar un servicio para estos casos es muy común.

Suerte ;)